# Is there any difference between actions in GTK and using signals directly?

Tags: python, gtk, gnome

It seems that actions and signals are very similar. Is there any difference between them? Actions are higher level than signals?

For example, I want to press a button to do something,
I can use action:

```xml
<object class="GtkButton">
  <property name="label">Start</property>
  <property name="action-name">app.start</property>
</object>
```

```py
class xxxApplication(Adw.Application):
    def on_button_clicked(self,widget,_):
        print('Button pressed.')
    
    def create_action(self):
        action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("start", None)
        action.connect("activate", self.on_button_clicked)
```

I can also use signals directly:

```xml
  <object class="GtkButton">
    <property name="label">Start</property>
    <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button_clicked"/>
  </object>
```

```py
class xxxWindow(Adw.ApplicationWindow):   
    @Gtk.Template.Callback()
    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        print('Button pressed.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the end result is the same, **actions** and **signals** have several differences. One of the main differences is that it is possible to add shortcuts to **actions**, but not to **signals**, at least not directly. Another important difference is that **actions** can be used directly on menu items, while **signals** are more difficult to use.

In general, **actions** are made with reuse throughout the application in mind, while **signals** are used in more specific situations. If you need a function that will be triggered by a keyboard shortcut, a menu item and a button, you can solve this with three **signal**s or with a single **action**.

There are also differences in the parameters passed to the function, **signals** are more flexible than **actions** in this sense.